# Infinitely Rich Objects In A Topos

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory

In the category of graphs I think one can find a graph $X$ that has a subgraph isomorphic to any finite graph $A.$

My question is, can this type of situation be generalized to a more general topos ? And if so, how ? In particular, is there an appropriate notion of an object being "finite" such that the following definition (1) makes sense, (2) refers to something existent, and (3) generalizes the graph case above:

*We define an object $X$ in a topos to be **infinitely rich** when, for any "finite" object $A$, there is a monomorphism $ A \rightarrowtail X.$*

Perhaps this kind of idea has already been studied, and if so I would like to know. Anyway, it looks like there are several different notions of finite objects in category theory. What I want is to select an appropriate idea of a "finite" object, so that an infinitely rich object can be found in my topos. My basic question is how to do this.

One idea I had is to suppose the topos is cocomplete, and then let $X$ be the coproduct of all the finite objects. However this requires that the finite objects form a small set.

Comment: Just a quick comment that your proposed definition is more complicated than it needs to be: if $H$ is isomorphic to $A$, and there is a monomorphism $H \to X$, then there is also a monomorphism $A \to X$ (just compose with the iso, which is mono). So you can simplify to just asking "... for any 'finite' $A$ there is a mono $A \to X$".

Comment: Good point, I will simplify it.

Comment: It seems that the notation of 'compact object' might be an appropriate notion of `finite' (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_object_(mathematics)).

Comment: After a very brief glance, I suspect that [Noetherian categories and objects](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/noetherian+category) are what you need to make your cocompleteness idea work. Essentially smallness is built into the definition, and most examples are pretty natural: the finite sets give rise to the subcategory of Noetherian objects of $\mathbf{Set}$: the same holds for finite dimensional vector spaces in $\mathbb{F}-\mathbf{Vect}$, and finite dimensional compact manifolds in the category of compact manifolds.

Comment: Thanks, maybe using Noetherian objects as finite objects might work, but I'm having a hard time seeing why the Noetherian objects in a topos will form a small set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any locally presentable category, the isomorphism classes of compact objects (that is, objects Homs out of which commute with filtered colimits) form a small set. This is a fundamental fact about locally presentable categories which can be found for instance in  Chapter 2 of Adamek and Rosicky’s book on the topic. Then your solution of taking the coproduct works great. Incidentally, this is probably the finiteness notion you want, as it coincides with the natural notion in any example of a topos you might name.

Luckily, “most” cocomplete toposes are locally presentable. In fact, Grothendieck toposes are precisely the locally presentable toposes. I cannot immediately produce an example of a cocomplete topos with a proper class of non-isomorphic compact objects. If $G$ is the large group given as a coproduct of representatives of every isomorphism class of finite group, then there is a cocomplete non-Grothendieck topos of small sets with a $G$-action, but it has only a small set of isomorphism classes of compact objects.